# Terraform module keeps modifying redis cache values from 200 to 642 for maxmemory delta ,reserved and fragmentation reserved attributes

Tags: azure, module, terraform-provider-azure

[image]

tried changing

whenever I rerun the pipeline module for redis cache keeps modifying the values to 642 from 200
the default values set is 200
and attributes are
maxfragmentation reserved
maxmemory  delta
maxmemory reserved

only this values changes others modules are not changing.

Comment: Please share the configuration you tried causing blocker @Ganesh

Comment: Are you using any dynamic block, if yes,  you can make use of a lifecycle block to prevent the changes in the configuration.


lifecycle {        ignore_changes = [          redis_configuration,        ]
      }

Comment: Hello Vinay ,I am not using any dynamic blocks in redis module.

Comment: Please share your configuration in query It will help in better understanding of your issue

Comment: Sorry ,I cant share the configuration.

Comment: @GaneshThorave You might find this useful: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/19892, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices-memory-management#configure-your-maxmemory-reserved-setting and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to rectify the issue causes the Terraform module keeps modifying Redis cache values from 200 to 642 for maxmemory delta, reserved, and fragmentation reserved attributes and I was able to figure out the issue causing this error.

From the image provided values of certain settings are being changed. It seems like the issue is that when you rerun your Terraform pipeline, the values for `maxfragmentationmemory_reserved`, `maxmemory_delta`, and `maxmemory_reserved` are reverting to `642` instead of staying at the intended `200`.

There are multiple issues that cause this to happen

- When these values are being set dynamically or calculated based on some other variable or output, and that calculation results in `642` instead of `200`.
- The Redis provider might be setting a default that overrides your value when it detects that the setting is below a certain threshold
- If you're using a managed Redis service from a cloud provider, the service itself might have certain defaults that it enforces, which could be overriding your settings.

Since I was not provided with enough information in the query I tried a demo version of the terraform configuration which suits the requirement mentioned.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "example" {
  name                = "vk-redis-cache"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  capacity            = 2
  family              = "C"
  sku_name            = "Standard"
  enable_non_ssl_port = false

  redis_configuration {
    maxmemory_reserved           = 200
    maxmemory_delta              = 200
    maxfragmentationmemory_reserved = 200
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

when I rerun the configuration without making any changes in code and execute the command **`terraform plan`** I have gone through the output mentioned.

[image]

This typically means that the actual configuration of the resource has deviated from what Terraform expects based on its state file

If the values are continually adjusted by the provider and it's not critical for them to be managed by Terraform, you could tell Terraform to ignore changes to these fields using the `lifecycle` block

**My Updated configuration:**

```
resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "example" {
  name                = "vk-redis-cache"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  capacity            = 2
  family              = "C"
  sku_name            = "Standard"
  enable_non_ssl_port = false

  redis_configuration {
    maxmemory_reserved           = 200
    maxmemory_delta              = 200
    maxfragmentationmemory_reserved = 200
  }

   lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      redis_configuration[0].maxfragmentationmemory_reserved,
      redis_configuration[0].maxmemory_delta,
      redis_configuration[0].maxmemory_reserved,
    ]
  }
}
```

**Output:**

**terraform plan:**

[image]

**terraform apply:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Vinay for your help .really appreciate your efforts here.